# Fatal error: Call to undefined function bindParam()

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

First of all, I already looked for the same questions, but couldn't find solutions. My db is working correctly. Everything is fine, except bindParam(). var_dump($expr) is also correct

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE student_id = :student_id and exam_no = :exam_no');
$student_id = $_POST['student_id'];
$academic_year = $_POST['academic_year'];
$exam_no = $_POST['exam_no'];

$stmt->bindParam(':student_id', $student_id);

$stmt->bindParam(':exam_no', $exam_no);

$stmt->execute();

$blah = $stmt->fetchAll();
$expr = $pdo->prepare('SELECT english FROM tbl WHERE student_id = :student_id and exam_no = :exam_no');
$expr = bindParam(':exam_no', $exam_no);
$expr = bindParam(':student_id', $student_id);
$expr->execute();
```

Getting: "Fatal error: Call to undefined function bindParam()" where $expr = bindParam() is located

Comment: That's because `bindParam` is not a function but a method of `PDOStatement`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`bindParam` is a method of [`PDOStatement`](http://php.net/pdostatement), not a global function. (*It's odd you did right at first but wrong at second.*)

Change

```
$expr = bindParam(':exam_no', $exam_no);
$expr = bindParam(':student_id', $student_id);
```

to

```
$expr->bindParam(':exam_no', $exam_no);
$expr->bindParam(':student_id', $student_id);
```

Comment: Ohhh, s**t. I didn't notice that, thank you)

Comment: @NoobEditor ?? What do you mean?

Comment: He wants to know what the nickname 'xdazz' stands for :)

Comment: @NoobEditor Errr, it has meaning for me but not for others.

Comment: @NoobEditor yeap, I'm waiting for that

Comment: @xdazz : okaz...random picked `chars` for me then... :D  deleting all my comments..nice meeting you fella! :D